Case to Ambient Resistance, D2PAK soldered to PCB
I'm trying to calculate junction to ambient thermal resistance of a D2PAK soldered to a PCB with no aluminium heatsink, no thermal vias (PCB is 4-layer 1 Oz/layer).
At 10A power dissipation of the D2PAK will be around 1.05W.
Mosfet datasheet gives RthJC (junction to case) = 0.4 C/W. Although it also gives RthJA (junction to ambient) = 40 C/W (when mounted on 1" square PCB (FR-4 material), I prefer to use the formula RthJA = RthJC + RthCA based on https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/mt-093.pdf
How can I get RthCA on this context?

40-0.4 is 39.6.
Of course if you want the answer for something other than a 1" square of FR-4, you will likely need to do some modeling or experimenting to get it.

Usually there will be a footnote to the stated Rth(j-a) value that points to an app note for calculating a more precise value. What is the part number of your device?

this is the datasheet https://www.vishay.com/docs/67027/sqm100n1.pdf

1.05W seems a mite on the optimistic side. Worst case with a 4.5V drive, 10A and 125°C Tj is almost 2.5x that, and still double (2W) even with 10V drive.

I did not mention some details for simplification like temperature inside case will be always under 35C with a dc fan always turned on and Vgs > 10V. In case of the scenario you mention Spehro some changes on the pcb will be needed, I agree with that.

This was surprisingly difficult to find relevant information for, as most of the app notes I could find assume 4-layer boards with thermal vias. However, TI AN-2020 is a good starting point, and the equations from table 1 can get you a rough approximation (but they might also push you towards using a calculator/simulator, especially if your geometry is complicated).
This Rohm app note shows that after 500 or 600 mm^2, diminishing returns kick in as the thermal gradient reduces the amount of heat that makes it to the edges of your pour, so don't expect too much from increasing your area beyond 1 square inch. Fortunately, 40 K/W is adequate for ~1 watt dissipation.
